# Should HSTS be declared on all assets, or just on HTML files?

Tags: tls, hsts

I am curious if the [HSTS response header](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) should be declared on every asset of a sitewide secure site, or just on the HTML pages? I imagine it should be included on all assets including all JS, CSS, PNG files but I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Same question answered here on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17635065/hsts-header-for-all-resources-or-documents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the policy of HSTS gets applied to the whole site it is enough that you sent it together with a resource which is definitely read by the client. This can be a HTML page, it can be an image, ...  as long as the client will definitely request this resource so that it knows the policy.

Comment: Thanks for this, then I am thinking it should be included on any file that a user may land on, in essence all HTML and all images, as they can be easily landed on through search.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing to say that this HTTP response header should be sent for HTML content types only.

As long as the header has a good chance of being received by the browser over HTTPS at the start of each session, then the policy will be adhered to until expiry (`max-age`), if not renewed by another response.